What is the significance of the Gray Heron being the only animal with a human head in "The Boy and the Heron"?
In Hayao Miyazaki's The Boy and the Heron (2023), the titular Heron was revealed to have a human (or human-looking) head inside its beak. At first, we only see human teeth and a nose, but later it was revealed to have a full human head inside its beak.

This sets the Gray Heron apart from the other animals in the movie. None of the animals in the other world within the tower share this unusual characteristic.
Could this be a reference to Japanese folklore, mythology, or another work? Is there a deeper meaning or symbolism behind this unique characteristic of the Gray Heron?
